# GeometryNodes: Grid and UV Map

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

assume a simple geometry nodes grid setup with a plane as instance. How do I manage to get the UVs mirrored so the texture of the plane will be seamless? (given the fact, that the texture is a procedural one.)

This is how the UVs are looking right now:

[image]

I'd preferably have this (which is made manualy to demonstrate the issue):

[image]

ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

Instances can be rotated (i.e. flipped) according row and column parity:

[image: GN graph]

Blender file: [image]

Comment: nice, thanks. May I ask how do I adapt this if the grid size is an unequal number like 5 x 5?

Comment: @Kristo: please - do not ask additional questions in comments. Just open a new question - you can open as many questions as you want. Explanation: people can search for questions here and find the answers only in questions or answers. Comments aren't searched by BSE and so cannot be found. Also your question was answered correctly, it is a bit unfair to ask then "more" questions in comments. Just formulate the next question with more detail, so that it is crystal clear that you wanna have a more general solution. thank you for your understanding.